# I'm using ajax to add to cart and it works fine on the details page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I use ajax to add to cart in details page it works fine but as a button in the products page where there is multiple ones it doesn't work.

I tried limiting the products to 1 and it worked .

So I guess the problem is that I'm using the same form id in multiple forms.

```html
<form method="POST" id="add_to_cartt">
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_id" value="<?php echo $final['id'];?>"   id="cart_id">
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_quantity" value="<?php echo "1" ?>">
    <button class="btn js-prd-addtocart" >Add To Cart</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_to_cartt').on('submit', function(e){
        //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
        e.preventDefault();
        var cart_id = $('#cart_id').val();
        var cart_quantity = $('#cart_quantity').val();
                    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'carthandler.php',
            data: {cart_id : cart_id, cart_quantity : cart_quantity,},
            success: function(data){}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, an ID must be unique (on a page).

Comment: Ok but is there another way i can submit the form by gaving it a class or a name

Comment: `is there another way i can submit the form by gaving it a class`...yes, exactly that. e.g. `$('.someClass').on('submit'` will add the same "submit" handler to all forms with the class `someClass`. Then you also need to amend the bits where you select `$('#cart_id')` and `$('#cart_quantity')`. Again use classes, and use `this.find(...)` to locate the specific field with that class within the form.

Comment: or use different IDs ...

Comment: @ADyson i tried using classes in cart_id and cart_quantity but i don't know how to use this.finf(..) can you please write the code

Comment: Try it first, there are examples at https://api.jquery.com/find/ and elsewhere. Come back if you're still stuck after making an attempt. Show us your attempt and explain what's still not working. `i don't know how to use this` isn't a reason for us to provide a free write-my-code service. We're not a substitute for reading the documentation. We'll _help_ you if you get stuck, but we won't replace your basic efforts.

Comment: I have been looking for more than an hour and nothing worked
i don't have much experience in js

Comment: Then please show us your best attempt as I mentioned, and explain where you got stuck. Please edit your question and add your latest code.